# Fatal exception of Type MWException

Tags: xampp, mediawiki, var, plesk, parallels

Hi i get this code in the beginning:

```
  [cc6ebde4] /kyrxa/index.php Exception from line 3279 of /var/www/mywiki/includes/GlobalFunctions.php: MediaWiki 1.24wmf6 required--this is only 1.23.0
```

And this at the end:

```
#0 /var/www/mywiki/extensions/VisualEditor/VisualEditor.hooks.php(23): wfUseMW(string)
#1 [internal function]: VisualEditorHooks::onSetup()
#2 /var/www/mywiki/includes/Setup.php(601): call_user_func(string)
#3 /var/www/mywiki/includes/WebStart.php(156): require_once(string)
#4 /var/www/mywiki/index.php(43): require(string)
#5 {main}
```

Answer (score 0):

The error message says it all, really: You are using a development version of [Extension:VisualEditor](https://www.mediawiki.org/wiki/Extension%3aVisualEditor), which requires MediaWiki version 1.24, whereas you have version 1.23 installed. To download VisualEditor for 1.23 with git you can do:

```
git checkout REL1_23
git submodule update
```

...or get it from [here](https://releases.wikimedia.org/VisualEditor/VisualEditor-MediaWiki-REL1_23.tar.bz2).

Note the VE extension, while used on Wikipedia, is still in beta, and might or might not work with you MW setup.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem after downloading the REL1_23 update they put on their page. I went to the repo and looked for the REL1_23 branch and downloaded the [zip](https://git.wikimedia.org/zip/?r=mediawiki/extensions/VisualEditor.git&h=98835665dc8bb994c03cf173701d2ae91191d473&format=zip). Worked like a charm.